# Generate a factor array and print it contents

Tags: java, arrays, methods, tostring, void

How to create a method that holds an array of integers, then allow that specific method to print all the elements of that array when ever the method is called from a main class?

Here is a program that I did as an example:
I am trying to find all the possible factors for an `int` input. I used a method called `generateFactors()` to store all the possible factors of a number, but I couldn't print the array elements for some reason. In the `toString()` method, there is an error saying `void type not allowed here`!

```js
public class FactorNumbers {

    private int number;

    public FactorNumbers(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void generateFactors() {
        int[] factors = new int[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            if ((i + 1 % number) == 0) {
                factors[i] = i;
                System.out.println("Factor= " + i);
            } else {
                factors[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.println(factors[i] + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The factors of " + number + "are: " + generateFactors();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't have generateFactors() in the toString method unless it actually returns a string.

Comment: You can have list of integers as member variable for the class.

Comment: The `generateFacors()` function doesn't return anything. Instead of printing out the numbers in `generateFactors()` function add those numbers to a list of some kind and return that instead of void.

Comment: Have your `generateFactors` method be a `String` return type, and then return the values of the array with `java.util.Arrays.toString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do what you want to do the code would have to look like this:

```
    public String generateFactors() {
    String ret = "";
    int[] factors = new int[number];

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        if ((i + 1 % number) == 0) {
            factors[i] = i;
            ret += "Factor= " + i + "\n";
        } else {
            factors[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        ret += factors[i] + "\n";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But, your code is not going to return the factors, I think what you really want to do is something like this:

```
 public String generateFactors() {
    String ret = "";
    int[] factors = new int[number];

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        //The remainder needs to be reversed
        if ((number % (i + 1)) == 0) {
            factors[i] = i+1;
        } else {
            factors[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        //only print them if they are a factor
        if(factors[i] != 0)
            ret += factors[i] + "\n";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new String at each iteration. You should use a StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 0):

The **toString()** method does not work with arrays and with methods having **void** as return. Instead use **Arrays.toString(array)** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FactorNumbers fn = new FactorNumbers(100);
    int[] factors = fn.generateFactors();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(factors));
}
```

inside your **main** method to print all those values contained in the array and refactor your **generateFactors()** method as :

```
public int[] generateFactors() {
        int[] factors = new int[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            if ((i + 1 % number) == 0) {
                factors[i] = i;
                System.out.println("Factor= " + i);
            } else {
                factors[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }
```

**NOTE :**
However, your code is not going to give you any factor because :

```
if ((i + 1 % number) == 0)
```

will always return false. Replace it with :

```
if((number % i+1) == 0)
```

to get the correct output.

Comment: He wants to return them not print them.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as below: 
You may use a stringbuilder if required.

```
 public String generateFactors() {
    int[] factors = new int[number];
    String strPrint = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        if ((i + 1 % number) == 0) {
            factors[i] = i;
            strPrint = strPrint + "Factor= " + i + "\n"
           //System.out.println("Factor= " + i);
        } else {
            factors[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        strPrint = strPrint + factors[i] + "\n"
       // System.out.println(factors[i] + "");
    }
   return strPrint;
}
```